# Couldn't get IoT Central offline command to work

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

Offline commands worked for Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester, but not my device. I am developing device that connects to IoT Central on Mqtt protocol.  I want to use the Offline command and follow the instruction on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-use-commands.  When I connect to the server using Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester, offline command seem to be working.  The command that executed on the IoT Central while device is disconnected is received by the Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester.  However, when I connect my device to the server, offline command never comes. My device receives the commands correctly when it is connected to the server.  But when command is executed while device is disconnected, the command is missing when the device connects.  To make sure that the server never sent the command I even find a way to log the TLS communication between device and server. Anyone had similar experience?

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am developing embedded system using a very uncommon programming language. however I can show you the data log.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ic54rntBxxSIpuG8E4TFp_Zx7JckaxF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ Steven please share the code in text in the above code

Comment: @Sampath I tried to post, but it's too long. Made it into text file 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i81In-xUQkyUo5RUhO7Rcrb4Ezk5BuzS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Steven share the main part.Only

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. In order for Offline command to work, have to set "clean start" bit to 0 in the MQTT CONNECT Packet.  It need to be a persistent-session.